1920x1080 screen resolution not available as an option for a monitor
I installed Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 on a HP computer with Intel on-board graphics.
When I connect it to some monitors it goes straight into 1920x1080 resolution, but there is one monitor I would like to use that is capable of displaying 1920x1080 but only gives the option of three resolutions up to 1024x768.
The monitor is an LG IPS235P-BN.
I have two of the same type of HP computers and it is the same problem on both of them. I also have a different Dell computer running the same Ubuntu version and the monitor boots fine to 1920x1080 on that.
I found and followed some instructions about using xrandr and cvt to find the available modes and set it but I still never got the extra option in display settings.
Sources: How do I set a custom resolution? and Unable to set my screen resolution higher
Is there some trick to making this work or can I install a driver for the monitor or something?
